# Finding rows with the maximum

Tags: sql, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

I have a pretty simple table in SQLite, with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Palettes 
             (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
             class TEXT, count INTEGER, name TEXT);
```

These represent color palettes, and several palettes can have the same name, but different counts (i.e. sizes).

What I want to do is find, for each set of named palettes, the one having the greatest (or least) count.

My first thought was to start with:

```
SELECT * FROM Palettes GROUP BY name;
```

But, of course, which row I get is arbitrary. Looking further, it seems that even if I do:

```
SELECT MAX("count"), * FROM Palettes GROUP BY name;
```

I still get an arbitrary row.
One last shot:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Palettes ORDER BY "count") GROUP BY name;
```

*seems* to work, but I cant find any guarantees anywhere.

Does someone have a solution to this problem? I can, of course, solve it in code, but I'd prefer an SQL solution, if possible.

Thanks,
-matt

Comment: I've added the `greatest-n-per-group` tag.  Click on that tag to see the answer in any of dozens of other questions here on SO.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction - I did look, but I'm barely an orange belt at SQL-fu, so I didn't get my search terms right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT P.*
  FROM Palettes AS P JOIN
       (SELECT name, MAX("count") AS max_count
          FROM Palette
         GROUP BY Name) AS MC
       ON MC.Name = P.Name AND P."count" = MC.Max_Count;
```

If there are several rows with the same maximum count for a particular name, you will get several rows returned.

I'm using double quotes around "count" because it is, of course, also a keyword; the double quotes convert the name into a delimited identifier.

Comment: Great - that will work for me. In this problem, if the name is non-null, then the name/count pair will be unique, so I don't have to worry about multiple rows (I can handle null-named palettes separately). Good to note about quoting "count" - SQLite managed parse the query even if I didn't quote it, but best to be safe. Thanks!